# Sprinkler Systems AND Irrigation Tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [sprinkler-system](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sprinkler-system) tag. And we have an [irrigation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrigation) tag. Obviously Sprinkler systems are a subset of irrigation, but there are 28 Sprinkler-system tags and 24 Irrigation tags.

Complicating things further, I expect Sprinklers and Sprinkler-systems are a more readily apparent terms to relatively new gardeners than irrigation is. I expect the proper course would be to re-tag all the Sprinkler questions, but frankly I don't want to go through 28 edits right now to fix this, and I'd rather not push all those old questions to the front page with edits either. Also, should Sprinkler-system be made a synonym for Irrigation?

Comment: For me irrigation is flood irrigation.  That's what I use.  Well, I also use drip irrigation (is that a sprinkler system?). I have no lawn and therefor no sprinkler system. Anyway sprinkler-system is really a subset.  So you should probably tag all sprinkler system tags with irrigation tags. Hey, is hand-watering irrigation?